# Using bash variable in input redirection with sort command

Tags: bash, variables, jenkins, input, command-substitution

I have a bash script written as follows in Jenkins Execute shell block

```
id="233"
```

I want to use this id variable inside following command

```
bash -c 'comm -12 <(sort file1_${id}.txt) <(sort file2_${id}.txt)'
```

But it throws error

```
sort: cannot read: file1_.txt: No such file or directory
sort: cannot read: file2_.txt: No such file or directory
```

I tried following but no luck and not sure how to fix

```
"$id"
"${id}"
'$id'
'${id}'
```

Answer (score 5):

Single quotes prevent `$id` from being expanded before `bash` runs, and the variable `id` isn't defined in the shell where then expansion of `$id` *is* attempted.

The simple (but fragile) solution is to use double quotes, so that `$id` expands to produce the command to run in the new shell.

```
bash -c "comm -12 <(sort file1_${id}.txt) <(sort file2_${id}.txt)"
```

A more robust solution is to pass the value of `$id` as an argument to the shell (and use double quotes *in* the command to protect the expansion of `$1`, should the value of `$id` require it).

```
bash -c 'comm -12 <(sort "file1_$1.txt") <(sort "file2_$1.txt")' bash "$id"
```

(The first argument following the script is used to set `$0`; it's value doesn't matter too much, but the name of the shell makes a good dummy argument.)

---

(I'm assuming `bash -c '...'` is required for some reason, and you can't simply use `comm -12 <(sort "file1_$id.txt") <(sort "$file2_$id.txt")` by itself.)

Answer (score 0):

```
bash -c 'comm -12 <(sort file1_'$id'.txt) <(sort file2_'$id'.txt)'
```

The above line works now

Comment: This is fragile, if the value of `$id` produces multiple words due to word-splitting or pathname expansion.

Comment: @chepner
Yes. 

but $id will be substituted with only one value always. So I think it woks for me now.

Comment: But you are not just answering your question for yourself. Others may have similar problems but without your constraints, and this will break for them.

Comment: @chepner

Ok. Cool